# How to determine if stepper motor will turn clockwise or counter clockwise initially

Tags: stepper-motor, power-electronics

Suppose we do not know the state of the rotor initially, then in this picture:
[image]

How would we apply voltages to coils 1 and 2 in order to ensure that the motor shaft will spin clockwise or counter clock wise from the beginning? For example, in the picture above with the rotor positioned as shown, if we reversed the voltage so that +V is on 1b and 1a is tied to ground, then couldn't the rotor rotate clockwise OR counter-clockwise?

Thanks!

Comment: My technique is to guess and if it's wrong, swap the polarity on one of the windings. Or fix it in software.

Comment: @alex.forencich I do hope you're not working on any supra-kW multiphase motors then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is literally in your own picture.

If you follow the sequence in the diagram downwards it will rotate forward, if you follow the sequence upward it will reverse. What is forward and what is reverse, well, it may or may not surprise you that not all motor manufacturers agree on that, but I'd suspect most would say forward is clockwise.

As for your own example, what happens in that case is just heat, because a stepper motor only rotates because of a series of pulses like in the diagram. Which way it will rotate when you go to the next step, depends on whether you follow that up with a + on 2a or on 2b.

And as a side note, generally if you make up your own sequence that doesn't fit the motor's diagram it'll whine, buzz and heat up more than actually move.

Comment: I don't understand, if you reverse the voltage applied, there should be a reversed magnetic field and in that case the rotor has to move either clockwise or counterclockwise one step in order for the magnetic field to align...

Comment: @lpbug Ah, I missed your 'reversed' there. Then yes. But that's generally why "we" don't do that and stick to the diagram. Although, there as well it will whine and heat more if you keep doing that, since the shorted coil 2 (both at 0V) will inhibit the movement of the other set of magnets. Unless "you're" keeping coil 2 out of it entirely, in which case "you're" missing the point of a two phase motor.

Comment: actually, i have one more followup: since we don't know the location of the rotor initially, if we follow the diagram how do we ensure that we will not get a few steps in the wrong direction?

Comment: @lpbug You don't know with just transistors driving it. There are chips that monitor the voltage-current-curve of the motor phases to see where it is before it starts stepping and then applies the state that the motor is already in. If you force a current that the rotor repulses (and thus which will make it rotate) the response is different from when you try to force a current that the rotor "likes". This difference can be seen before there is enough energy to rotate away.